# Nest can't resolve dependency of rsservice_EntityRepo. make sure that argument rsserviceDataSource at index [0] is available in RootTestModule context

Tags: node.js, jestjs, nest, ts-jest

I am trying to write unit test case for strategy module. Which uses repository of imported AppOnboarding Module.

Strategy Module:

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AppOnboardingEntity], 'recipientservice'), AppOnboardingModule],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [StrategyRegistryService, EmailStrategyService, SmsStrategyService, WebhookStrategyService, PushStrategyService, CustomLoggerService],
  exports: [StrategyRegistryService]
})
export class StrategyRegistryModule { }
```

AppOnboarding Module:

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AppOnboardingEntity, AppOnboardingRepository],'recipientservice')],
  providers: [AppOnboardingRepository],
  exports: [AppOnboardingRepository]
})

export class AppOnboardingModule {}
```

strategy-registry.service.unit.test.ts:

```
  beforeAll(async () => {

    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        StrategyRegistryModule,
        AppOnboardingModule,
        WinstonModule.forRoot({
          transports: [new winston.transports.Console()]
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(AppOnboardingEntity, 'recipientservice'),
          useFactory: mockAppOnboardingRepository
        },
        StrategyRegistryService,
        CustomLoggerService,

      ]
    }).compile();
```

```
  const mockAppOnboardingRepository: any = () => ({
    findOne: jest.fn(),
    fetchDeviceList: jest.fn(),
    fetchRecipientsFromRecGroupIds: jest.fn()
  });
```

I am getting error mentioned below:
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the recipientservice_AppOnboardingEntityRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument recipientserviceDataSource at index [0] is available in the TypeOrmModule context.
Potential solutions:
- If recipientserviceDataSource is a provider, is it part of the current TypeOrmModule?
- If recipientserviceDataSource is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within TypeOrmModule?
@Module({
imports: [ /* the Module containing recipientserviceDataSource */ ]
})

How can we mock the repository which is exported from different module?

Comment: I don't think you need to export `AppOnboardingRepository` from `AppOnboarding`, nor import `AppOnboardingModule` in `StrategyRegistryModule`. `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([AppOnboardingEntity])` should be enough for you to use `AppOnboardingEntity` within `StrategyRegistryModule`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. but we have created custom repository in a module for future requirement and exported that from module. and also AppOnboarding module doesn't contain any service as of now.